# Subsetting an “xts” (matrix) with NAs

Tags: r, xts, subset

Consider the following xts objects, x,y:

```
x=xts(matrix(1:12, ncol=3), Sys.Date()+1:4  )
x[1,]=NA   
y=x
```

As all elements are positive:

```
>     coredata(x)[x>0]
[1] NA  2  3  4 NA  6  7  8 NA 10 11 12
>     coredata(y)[T]
[1] NA  2  3  4 NA  6  7  8 NA 10 11 12
```

To further confirm similiarities we can check:

```
>     str(coredata(x)[x>0])  
int [1:12] NA 2 3 4 NA 6 7 8 NA 10 ...
>     class(coredata(x)[x>0])  
[1] "integer"
>     str(coredata(y)[T])  
int [1:12] NA 2 3 4 NA 6 7 8 NA 10 ...
>     class(coredata(y)[T])  
[1] "integer"
```

Anyway, when it comes to assignment there is a different behaviour

```
>     coredata(x)[x>0]=0
>     coredata(y)[T]=0
>     x;y
           [,1] [,2] [,3]
2014-01-15   NA   NA   NA
2014-01-16    0    0    0
2014-01-17    0    0    0
2014-01-18    0    0    0

           [,1] [,2] [,3]
2014-01-15    0    0    0
2014-01-16    0    0    0
2014-01-17    0    0    0
2014-01-18    0    0    0
```

Can you explain why there is a different behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

From `help("[")`:

> #### NAs in indexing
>
> When extracting, a numerical, logical or character NA index picks an
> unknown element and so returns NA in the corresponding element of a
> logical, integer, numeric, complex or character result, and NULL for a
> list. (It returns 00 for a raw result.)
>
> When replacing (that is using indexing on the lhs of an assignment) NA
> does not select any element to be replaced. As there is ambiguity as
> to whether an element of the rhs should be used or not, this is only
> allowed if the rhs value is of length one (so the two interpretations
> would have the same outcome).